# MongoDB server start issue

Tags: database, mongodb, server, permissions, permission-denied

I'm having an issue with starting my MongoDB server. I didn't have this issue before but after the weekend (where my VM restart itself - unsure if related), it seems to be making an error each time i start the DB. 
I had the server running as a service automatically at startup, but this gave permission issues for some reason, so when i manually start it, there was no issues, until now.
Anyway i have posted a screen-grab of what the terminal is returning.
Hope someone can shine some light on what might be causaing this issue.
Thanks, |Conor.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running powershell as administrator?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots and actually read that big message on the add picture pop-up that told you the same thing. You can simply copy the text off of the screen. The error says "permission denied". So you either previously ran this under a different or privileged account. Fix the permissions.

Comment: Admin fixed it, thanks all.